# Make a function that returns the mean of an array

Tags: java, arrays

When I attempt to compile the code, command says I have a error where i put total = total + int[i]; Is this the correct way to add the elements of the array together or is there a better way to do this?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class main{

    private static void findMean(int[] input){
            int total = 0;         
        for(i = 0; i < array.length; i++){


            total = total + int[i];

        } 
        mean = total/n;
        System.out.println(mean);
    }   


    public static void main(String[] args){
      Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);  // Reading from System.in
      System.out.println("How many numbers do you want");
      int n = reader.nextInt();
      int[] numbers;
      numbers = new int[n];


      for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){     
        System.out.println("Enter number " + i + 1 );
        numbers[i] = reader.nextInt();
            }

     findMean(numbers);

    }
}
```

I want the code to display the mean, instead, I get the following error:

```
main.java:11: error: illegal start of expression
            total = total + [i];
                            ^
main.java:11: error: not a statement
            total = total + [i];
                             ^
main.java:11: error: ';' expected
            total = total + [i];
                              ^
```

Comment: Use `total = total + input[i];` The name of *your* array is input and not int. The same thing applies to the for-loop

Comment: You need to read up about arrays; how you declare them, how to initialize them, and how to retrieve the value of an array elemen.

Comment: Thanks guys, this worked I am still very new

Comment: Problem is at the total = total + int[i]; .. change it with .. total = total + input[i]; , as input is the name of the array variable. and change your loop too from for(i = 0; i < array.length; i++) , to for(i = 0; i < input.length; i++)

Comment: This solution works for most arrays, but not all. Suppose one of the array values is Integer.MAX_INT (or near it). The summation will overflow and you will get the wrong answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your input parameter is named `input`, `int[]` is just the type.
Give it a try with:

```
total = total + input[i];
```

Another way would be streams...

Best regards

Alex

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the array elements reading issue and updating total value.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class main{

    private static void findMean(int[] input){
        int total = 0;         
        for(int i = 0; i < input.length; i++){

            total = total + input[i];

        } 
        double mean = total/n;
        System.out.println(mean);
    }   


    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);  // Reading from System.in
        System.out.println("How many numbers do you want");
        int n = reader.nextInt();
        int[] numbers;
        numbers = new int[n];


        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){     
            System.out.println("Enter number " + i + 1 );
            numbers[i] = reader.nextInt();
        }

        findMean(numbers);

    }
}
```